# Flash movieclip displayed in second screen

Tags: flash, screen, projector

I'm doing an Flash interactive - one screen is a touch screen and one screen is a overhead projector.

On the touch screen a user has the option to change the colour of movieclips - once the user is happy with the colours the results need to be displayed on the overhead projector (i.e. on a second screen)

Whilst a total solution would be perfect I'm just looking for pointer in the right direction please - preferably using actionscript 2 (if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are intending these to be 2 separate SWF's? Take a look at use of [LocalConnection](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/LocalConnection.html). This will allow you to pass data between both SWF's.

Comment: local connection worked perfectly thanks - this artlce was very helpful http://fcontheweb.com/articles/localconnection/